# Finding all rows where FLOAT number has more than 8 significant digits with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking at a way to find all rows in a Oracle database table where the value in a specific column of FLOATs has more than eight significant digits.

I am thinking that there might be some smart mathematical way of identifying the rows but I just cant think of any.

The following numbers should be accepted:

- 123456789
- 123456789.123
- 123456789.01
- 0.123456789

But not the following

- 123000000.000
- 0.1234567
- 1.1234567

The only solution I have come up with so far, which I don't even know if it really works, looks like this, but is very slow to run, is there a faster way?

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE LENGTH(TO_CHAR(ABS(field))) > 9;
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to solve this since there's no way to inspect a number and determine how many digits are actually significant. Certainly, for example, `123000000.000`. Why is *that* invalid but `123000001.000` or `122999999.000` would be valid? You can't automatically determine that trailing `0`s (before the decimal) aren't significant.

Comment: Floating point values are stored as binary. When converting to/from character representation, some rounding issues may give a very unexpected result. What looks like a few decimals float, is stored as something similar - but rounded, and returned with many decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific definition of `significance` I think there aren't any better ways. Even more your proposed solution isn't quite right, it'd be mistaken on `123000000.00` or even `123456.7`. So you need to remove `.` and trailing zeros:

```
with data (a) as 
(
  select 12345678 from dual union all
  select 12345678.0 from dual union all
  select 12345678.1 from dual union all
  select 1234567 from dual union all
  select 123456789.234 from dual union all
  select 0.123456789 from dual
)
select
  *
from data
where
  length(rtrim(replace(to_char(abs(a)), '.'), '0')) >= 8
```

Unfortunately I haven't Oracle DB to test it. But I have MS Sql Server, so I ported it and tested:

```
with data (a) as 
(
  select 12345678 union all
  select 12345678.0 union all
  select 12345678.1 union all
  select 1234567 union all
  select 123456789.234 union all
  select 0.123456789
)
select
  *
from data
where
  len(rtrim(replace(replace(str(abs(a)), '.', ''), '0', ' '))) >= 8
```

The difference is just in Oracle => Sql Server:

- `rtrim('..', '0')` => `rtrim(replace('...', '0', ' '))`,
- `length` => `len`